# How to intent python?

Tags: android, android-intent, qpython3

I'm using QPython3 on my Android, but I have no idea how to intent code.

I have tried using

```
d.startActivity('android.intent.action.MAIN')
```

But I might be implementing it wrong.

My code right now:

```
question = input("Say a number: ")
answer = int(questioned) % 2 
a = 1
if int(answer) < 1:
d.startActivity('android.intent.action.MAIN'
print("even")
else
d.startActivity('android.intent.action.MAIN'
print("odd")
```

Error message:

> line 5
>       d.startActivity('android.intent.action.MAIN'
>       ^
>   IndentationError: expected an indented block
>   1|dreamlte:/ $

(The intents you see appeared when I but the code in Stack.)

Comment: You're missing closing parenthesis after `startActivity(...`. You should have `d.startActivity('android.intent.action.MAIN') print("...")` instead of `d.startActivity('android.intent.action.MAIN' print("...")`.

Comment: Your code is also not in**d**ented correctly. You need to fix your indentation, with a "d" not a "t". You're misreading your error message, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Python relies on indenting to define scope.
So code in the branches of your if-else needs to be indented.

```
question = input("Say a number: ")
answer = int(questioned) % 2 
a = 1

if int(answer) < 1:
    d.startActivity('android.intent.action.MAIN')
    print("even")
else:
    d.startActivity('android.intent.action.MAIN')
    print("odd")
```